# HTML resizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried using this same method from :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_image2

I see that when the w3schools when i resize it , the picture also will resize with the width and height.

In my case , when I adapt the same code. My image cropped just to the top left . Not the whole image:

Is there something i missed out?

JsBIN:
http://jsbin.com/doyaseyabu/edit?html,css,output

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>About Page template By Adobe Dreamweaver CC</title>
<link href="AboutPageAssets/styles/aboutPageStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script><script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/montserrat:n4:default;source-sans-pro:n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>


function load() {
 var context = document.getElementById('main').getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://via.placeholder.com/75x150";
img.onload = function () {

    context.drawImage(img, 250, 0);
}

}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="load();">
<!-- Header content -->
<header>
  <div class="profileLogo"> 
    <!-- Profile logo. Add a img tag in place of <span>. -->
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Name :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Attempts :</span></p>
    <p class="logoPlaceholder"><!-- <img src="logoImage.png" alt="sample logo"> --><span>Score :</span></p>
  </div>
  <section>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="canvas-container">

      <canvas id="main" width="500px" height="250px"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </section>
  <!-- Links to Social network accounts -->
  <aside class="socialNetworkNavBar">
    <div style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" >

      </div>
    <div id="left" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" > </div>
    <div id="down" style="margin-right: 50px;" class="socialNetworkNav"> 
      <!-- Add a Anchor tag with nested img tag here --> 
      <input id="right"  type="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" >
 </div>

  </aside>
</header>
<!-- content -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Global Styles */
#main {
    width:100%;
    background-image:url('http://www.desktopwarehouse.com/wallpapers/christmas-tree-background-852x480.jpg');
}   
body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 92%;
    max-width: 960px;
    padding-left: 2.275%;
    padding-right: 2.275%;
}
/* Header */
header {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
header .logoPlaceholder span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .logoPlaceholder2 span {
    width: 180px;
    height: 22px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 53px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    background-color: rgba(237,237,237,1.00);
    width: 259px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 259px;
    clear: both;
}
header .profileHeader h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
header .profileHeader h3 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 24px;
}
hr {
    background-color: rgba(208,207,207,1.00);
    height: 1px;
}
header .profileHeader p {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgba(146,146,146,1.00);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.8;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    clear: both;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Media query for Mobile devices*/
@media only screen and (min-width : 285px) and (max-width : 480px) {
/* Header */
#main {

width:100%;

}   
header {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}   
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    display: inline-block;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
header .profileHeader p {
    text-align: justify;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 60px;

    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Media Query for Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* Header */
header {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 7%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}

}

/* Desktops and laptops  */
@media only screen and (min-width:1025px) {
/* Header */
header .profileLogo .logoPlaceholder {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
header .profilePhoto {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
header .profileHeader {
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
header .socialNetworkNavBar .socialNetworkNav {
    width: 74px;
    height: 74px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 23px;
}



.wrapper {
   display: table;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.container {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
.canvas-container {
   position: relative;
   max-width: 1024px;
   min-width: 120px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}



}
```

Image issue :-

On website:
[image: Original width]

On mobile :

[image: After resize it cut only the top left not resize the whole image]

Comment: @ℊααnd, for the main class `background-image:url('http://www.desktopwarehouse.com/wallpapers/christmas-tree-background-852x480.jpg');`

Comment: In your JS Bin I doesn't see any problem. Can you explain your problem more precisely?

Comment: @kris_IV, the issue is when on browser it show the image correctly as when it resizes to mobile, it should by right resize the whole image to fit it. But in my case, it only resize up to the top left where the remaining picture are missing.

Comment: Try this: background-size: cover

Comment: @kris_IV, that actually fixed it when i put in the main css. But i'm curious why the w33 school differs from mine. Is it because it's a table?

Comment: Your [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/doyaseyabu/edit?html,css) working perfectly fine with `background-size: cover`. I don't see a problem on website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the style `background-size: cover` for the canvas element *(`#main`)* , as you are not using an actual image element but, setting a background image for the canvas.

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.desktopwarehouse.com/wallpapers/christmas-tree-background-852x480.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```